# Typescript compilation becomes slow - WebStorm

Tags: performance, node.js, compilation, typescript

Since some days I see that the typescript compilation is becoming slower and slower. Compile a single file with webstorm file watcher took me around 1-4 sec, but I added many TS files (75 now, and I think that's not really a lot...) and the compilation time is about 10sec for a simple file.

If I need to change of branch or update a definition, it can become around 5 minutes. My computer is really powerful (game computer) and I don't get why it's becoming slow like that.

All files are compiled one by one, the webstorm way... And if the server is running at the same time with a watcher, it becomes crazy because restart maybe 50 times. (Obviously, I shut it down, but it's not really useful to have a watcher if I need to shut it down...)

Any idea? I took a look to several discussions like mine but so far I didn't really found any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You could point the file watcher to grunt task that compiles all your files in a single pass. E.g. grunt-ts : https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts compiles all your files in one command to tsc.

PS disclosure: I am one of the authors of grunt-ts

Comment: I found your module, I already use grunt, I was just afraid to make my project more complicated by using grunt intensively and because my project is really **complicated**, using AMD and CommonJS with inheritance and dependencies, I was also afraid that would not work or I would need a lot of work to make it works.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see why the compilation ts -> js would be faster using a watcher.

Comment: WebStorm IDE added its own compiler in the 10.x version. That could be another way to deal with the issue. https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/#typescriptcompiler